# How to sort out elements in two-dimensional list this way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a two-dimensional list (which is always square-like) like this:

```
[[a1,a2,a3], [b1,b2,b3], [c1,c2,c3]]
```

I need to make 27 lists which consist of elements like this:

```
[a1+b1+c1],[a1+b1+c2],[a1+b1+c3],......,[a3+b3+c2],[a3+b3+c3]
```

I could use algoritm like this if a main list will always consist of 3 elements:

```
for i in list[0]
     for j in list[1]:
         for k in list[2]:
             some_func(i,j,k)
```

But my problem is that length of a main list differs every time.
Is there any trick? 
Thank you!

Comment: can you use `itertools` or do you *have* to have a pure-python solution ?

Comment: `But my problem is that length of a main list differs every time` Meaning?

Comment: @mad_ meaning he can have `n` lists inside the main list, and he doesnt know `n` beforehand. So he can't do a loop solution as he proposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `product` from `itertools`

```
>>> from itertools import product

>>> a =[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]

>>> print ([i for i in product(*a)])
[(1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 7), (1, 4, 8), (1, 4, 9), (1, 5, 6), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (1
, 5, 9), (2, 4, 6), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 4, 9), (2, 5, 6), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5
, 8), (2, 5, 9), (3, 4, 6), (3, 4, 7), (3, 4, 8), (3, 4, 9), (3, 5, 6), (3, 5, 7
), (3, 5, 8), (3, 5, 9)]

>>> print ([sum(i) for i in product(*a)])
[11, 12, 13, 14, 12, 13, 14, 15, 12, 13, 14, 15, 13, 14, 15, 16, 13, 14, 15, 16,
 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

This works by taking the Cartesian product of each of the sub-lists and summing each of them.

Of course, this can be shortened to:

```
>>> print (list(map(sum, product(*a))))
[11, 12, 13, 14, 12, 13, 14, 15, 12, 13, 14, 15, 13, 14, 15, 16, 13, 14, 15, 16,
 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

using `map` to disregard the for loop.

Comment: `what is the purpose of the `for` loop? is `list(product(*a))` not enough?

Comment: @Onyambu I guess he just wanted to show what is each *i* so to be clear what `sum(i)` does later on

Comment: @Onyambu Although the for loop is unnecessary, it helps to explain what is going on.  Find me over at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com if you want brevity ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools.product

```
>>> import itertools
>>> s=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> list(map(sum, itertools.product(*s)))
[12, 13, 14, 13, 14, 15, 14, 15, 16, 13, 14, 15, 14, 15, 16, 15, 16, 17, 14, 15, 16, 15, 16, 17, 16, 17, 18]
```